# SASS/CSS Hot Reload not working with Webpack 3

Tags: css, webpack

Webpack is clearly correctly watching for changes and rebuilding my modules, because when I refresh the page, any style changes go into effect. But without refreshing, the message simply says `App hot update.` but the styles don't change.

Here's my config; Note that we are using SASS and only using the ExtractTextPlugin for Production builds. (For simplicity's sake, I've edited out our production config)

```
module.exports = function(env: {production:boolean}) {

return {
  context: __dirname, // to automatically find tsconfig.json
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      moment: 'moment/moment.js',
    },
    extensions: ['.scss', '.ts', '.js']
  },

  plugins: [
     new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /@angular/,
        path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')
        ),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
           { from: 'src/static' }
        ]),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin({
        multiStep: true
        }),
        new HappyPack({
              id: 'ts',
              threads: 2,
              loaders: [
                 {
                    path: 'ts-loader',
                    query: { happyPackMode: true }
                 }
              ]
        }),
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin()   
  ]

  entry: ['./src/app/main.ts'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + "/public/"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },

  devtool: 'source-map',

  devServer: {

    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    inline: false,
    progress: true,
    port: 3000,
    contentBase: 'public',
    proxy: {
      '*': {
        target: 'http://localhost:9657/',
        secure: false
        }
     }
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
        {
        test: /\.svg/,
        loader: 'svg-url-loader',
        options: {}
        },
        {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: 'json-loader'
        },
        {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
        },
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?sourceMap!sass-loader?sourceMap&sourceComments'
        } 
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hot reload often does not work because it tries to load something.hot-reload.json

If it cannot get it then it will 404 and hot reload will not work. Here, you need to fix the path that webpack is requesting from.

If it is not requesting the file then something is wrong with your config.